# constrOptim in R - init val is not in the interior of the feasible region error

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I am trying to use `constrOptim` package. Here is my set up:

```
test_func <- function(x){
  return((x%*%x)[1,1])
}
constrOptim(rep(1/3,3), f=test_func,grad = NULL,
            ui = rbind(diag(3),rep(1, 3), rep(-1,3)),
            ci = c(rep(0,3),1,-1), method = "Nelder-Mead")
```

it generates error:

> ```
>    Error in constrOptim(rep(1/3, 3), f = test_func, grad = NULL, ui = rbind(diag(3),  : 
>       initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region
> ```

it is easy to check that my initial value is in the interior of the feasible region (which is from docs: `ui %*% theta - ci >= 0`)
[constrOptim](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html)

```
ui %*% rep(1/3, 3) - ci
```

produces:

```
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3333333
[2,] 0.3333333
[3,] 0.3333333
[4,] 0.0000000
[5,] 0.0000000
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search Google you get an answer from @HongOoi in the comments of another question with a similar error message. Hong Ooi suggested subtracting a fuzz value from the `ci` argument:

```
  fuzz = - 1e-6


 constrOptim(rep(1/3,3), f=test_func,grad = NULL,
             ui = rbind(diag(3),rep(1, 3), rep(-1,3)),
             ci = c(rep(0,3),1,-1)- 1e-6, method = "Nelder-Mead")
#---------------------
$par
[1] 0.3333317 0.3333327 0.3333346

$value
[1] 0.3333327

$counts
[1] 0

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$outer.iterations
[1] 1

$barrier.value
[1] 0.000209865
```

I think this is probably an issue that might warrant sending a request to the R-devel mailing list for documentation improvement, although arguable you are not actually in the *interior* of the feasible range since the constraint tes fails a strict inequality:

```
 ui %*% rep(1/3,3) - ci > 0
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE
[4,] FALSE
[5,] FALSE
```

Your first three constraints were satisfied by the inequality but not the last two which were *on* the boundary.

Comment: Thank you, I actual ended up using `Rsolnp` package. It can handle qualities as well.

Comment: I searched for an identical question that had an accepted answer but failed. I found several like yours that had not been answered. Future searchers might find this more easily if you checkmarked it.